# Using DateTime to compare the current date with another date

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I'm just starting to look at the JODA library and I want to take the current time and see if it falls within 3 days of a timestamp in the DB.

I'm looking at the example on their API:

```
public boolean isRentalOverdue(DateTime datetimeRented) {
  Period rentalPeriod = new Period().withDays(2).withHours(12);
  return datetimeRented.plus(rentalPeriod).isBeforeNow();
}
```

I am taking a String from the database to create a Date object:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(startDate);
```

How can I see if Date object in my code falls within 3 days of the current time?:

```
Period threeDays = new Period().withDays(3);
boolean withinThreeDays = date.plus(threeDays).isBeforeNow();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get not parse Joda date from string, and check without `SimpleDateFormat` and `Period`

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(startDate);  
boolean withinThreeDays = dateTime.plusDays(3).isBeforeNow();
```

Comment: Changed to isAfterNow() and it worked 100%. Thanks for this information, appreciate it.